# How do I check from a view controller or class if a specific view controller is visible on screen? Or how do I check visible view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

In my app I have a chat view controller. When this controller is presented (visible on screen) I don't want to receive push notifications from firebase. Otherwise yes.
I handle the notifications in a separate class, in which I want to do something like this, but **I don't have access to that variable, neither to an instance of that chat controller**:

```
If !ChatViewController.isOnScreen {
    sendPushNotification()
}
```

A created an extension, but I don't know why I can't use it. This is it:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public var isOnScreen: Bool {
        if isViewLoaded {
            return view.window != nil
        }
        return false
    }

    public var isTopViewController: Bool {
        if self.navigationController != nil {
            return self.navigationController?.visibleViewController === self
        } else if self.tabBarController != nil {
            return self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController == self && self.presentedViewController == nil
        } else {
            return self.presentedViewController == nil && self.isOnScreen
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `isViewLoaded ` ?

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't know why I can't use it"? It throws an error? It crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have that view controller's instance, what you can do is to create a statice variable in the view controller and set that to true when the controller is visible and false when it is invisible.
Here's some sample code. In your `ChatViewController`

```
public static var isOnScreen = false

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  isOnScreen = true
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
  isOnScreen = false
}
```

Now you can check this variable any time to know if the controller is visible or not like this.

```
if ChatViewController.isOnScreen {
}
```

Comment: Exactly how I did before you answered. Thanks!